# FONT.COLOR returns NULL in conditional formatting excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, conditional-statements

I have a sub routine which gets conditional formatting properties cell by cell in sheet "Source" and applies them in sheet "Result" in the same workbook. It works properly just when I get Font.Color and Font.TintAndShade it returns null, so in the Result sheet all the conditional formatting have black font color. (You can check it in Result Sheet Conditional Formatting > Mange Rules).

The error is "Invalid use of Null" maybe it is because of type of values.

Error occurs here:

```
FCFontC = Xarr(I, J).FormatConditions(II).Font.Color
FCFOntT = Xarr(I, J).FormatConditions(II).Font.TintAndShade
```

here is my code:

```
Sub FormatCondition1()
Dim FC As FormatCondition
Dim FCFontC As Long 
Dim FCFOntT As Integer
Dim FCC As Long
Dim FCT As Integer
Dim II As Integer
Dim Wks1 As Worksheet, Wks2 As Worksheet
Dim Xarr As Range, Yarr As Range
Dim I As Integer, J As Integer
'Dim K As Integer, L As Integer

Worksheets("Source").Activate
Worksheets("Result").Select

Set Yarr = Worksheets("Result").Range("A1:C2")
Yarr.Range("A1:C2").Clear

Set Wks1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Source")
Set Wks2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Result")

Set Xarr = Wks1.Range("A1:C2")
Set Yarr = Wks2.Range("A1:C2")

For I = 1 To Xarr.Rows.Count
    For J = 1 To Xarr.Columns.Count
        If Xarr(I, J).FormatConditions.Count > 0 Then
            For II = 1 To Xarr(I, J).FormatConditions.Count 'II number of conditions
                Set FC = Xarr(I, J).FormatConditions.Item(II)

                'cell font formatting
                '**** Error is HERE *******
                FCFontC = Xarr(I, J).FormatConditions(II).Font.Color
                FCFOntT = Xarr(I, J).FormatConditions(II).Font.TintAndShade

                'cell interior formating
                'Set FCCIn = Xarr.FormatConditions(II).Interior.PatternColorIndex
                 FCC = Xarr(I, J).FormatConditions(II).Interior.Color
                 FCT = Xarr(I, J).FormatConditions(II).Interior.TintAndShade

                'SET PROPERTY to NEW CELL
                Yarr(I, J).Select
                Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:= _
                    FC.Operator, Formula1:=FC.Formula1
                'Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

                'cell font formatting
                Selection.FormatConditions(II).Font.Color = FCFontC
                Selection.FormatConditions(II).Font.TintAndShade = FCFOntT

                'cell interior formating
                With Selection.FormatConditions(II).Interior
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .Color = FCC
                    .TintAndShade = FCT
                End With
                Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).StopIfTrue = False
            Next II
        End If
    Next J
Next I
```

End Sub

My question is "How I can get property of conditional formatting fonts also?